# flutter how to compare two different format phone numbers

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find if two phone numbers are same or not (Two same phone number may not be in the same format, as `+919998245345` is same as `9998245345` and `99982 45345`)

Comment: There are multiple packages dealing with input and formatting. Once your phone number have the same format, comparing them should be easy. For example https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libphonenumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you can use [contains()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/String/contains.html) **dart string method**. I have marked the trailing statement as bold, cos, it applies on the `String`. Make sure you get the number in String format, or convert it to String and then perform the operation.

**Alogrithm**

> 1. Convert the number to be compared to String, or get the number as String
> 2. Remove all the white spaces using this code, `your_phone_number_variable.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), "")`. So that every number should be having no white spaces in between for smooth operation
> 3. Use `contains()` like this, number1.contains(number2)

**Code**

```
// this is a comparision between +919998245345 and other numbers
// you can play around and get what you want
void main() {
  var _inputPhone = "+919998245345";
  var _checkPhone = "9998245345";
  var _anotherCheck = "99982 45345";
  
  // checking that white space removal works or not
  print(_anotherCheck.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), ""));
  
  // I have just removed the spaces from the number which had the white
  // space, you can store the value using this code for every data
  // for unknown data coming from server side or user side
  _anotherCheck = _anotherCheck.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"\s+"), "");
  if(_inputPhone.contains(_anotherCheck)){
    print('99982 45345 and +919998245345 are same');
  }
  
  if(_inputPhone.contains(_checkPhone)){
    print('9998245345 and +919998245345 are same');
  }
  
}
```

**Output**

```
9998245345
99982 45345 and +919998245345 are same
9998245345 and +919998245345 are same
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  print(isSame('9998245345', '+91999824 5345'));
}

bool isSame(String number1, String number2) {
  number1 = number1.replaceAll(' ', '');
  number2 = number2.replaceAll(' ', '');
  int len1 = number1.length;
  int len2 = number2.length;
  number1 = number1.substring(len1-10, len1);
  number2 = number2.substring(len2-10, len2);
  return number1 == number2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the simple and best solution to chnage format of phone

```
String changeFormat(String phone) {
    phone = phone.replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (phone.startsWith("+")) {
      return "0" + phone.substring(3);
    } else {
      return phone;
    }
  }
```